# Core Data : UI Freeze when I try to fetch

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I am trying to fetch all the entities from the container asynchronously but the way I do still makes my UI freeze. My question is how can I fetch all the data from Core Data fast without stopping my UI to stop.

Here is the function I use to do in Persistence file

> PersistenceController

```
public lazy var mainMoc: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let mainMoc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    mainMoc.parent = backgroundMoc
    return mainMoc
}()


public lazy var backgroundMoc: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let privateMoc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateMoc.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.coordinator
    return privateMoc
}()


func fetchStories(limit: Int, completion: @escaping (Result<[Story], PersistenceError>) -> Void) {
    backgroundMoc.perform {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Story")
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Story.timestamp, ascending: false)]
        request.fetchLimit = limit

        do {
            let stories = try self.mainMoc.fetch(request) as! [Story]
            completion(.success(stories))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(.noStoriesFound))
        }
    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please confirm, why are we fetching records in background. Do you want to show them in UI or wanted to do some other heavy operation.

Here are few suggestions -

1. If you want to fetch the records and show them in UI then use `mainMoc` instead of `backgroundMoc`.
2. Add batchSize in fetchRequest as below:

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Story.timestamp, ascending: false)]
request.fetchLimit = limit
request.batchSize = 10
```

This will fetch limited records at a time, and on load more, the core data will automatically fetch remaining objects in memory.

Comment: I found out about NSFetchResultCOntroller this morning and I am about to look for it! But the batch size does help me. Thank you!

Comment: If you are using in foreground for displaying on screen, then NSFetchedResultsController is the best option. And if you want to dynamically update your data like on edit/update/delete from backend response, then also use it's delegate. And then execute with `performBatch` or tableview's `beginUpdates()` `insert/delete/reload row/section operations` and then `endUpdates()`